# Error PARSE ERROR: SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED 'DATA' (T_STRING) IN

Tags: php

```html
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            header("Content-type: Imagenes/jpg"); 
      $salida.="<tr>
         <td>".$fila['Num_reg']."</td>
         <td>".$fila['Dni']."</td>
         <td>".$fila['Documento']."</td>
         <td>".$fila['Contacto']."</td>
         <td>".$fila['Ubigeo']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['Fec_publicacion']."</td>
                        <td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($fila['imagen']);?>"/></td>
                        
        </tr>";
            

     }
     $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    }
```

Me esta este error:
PARSE ERROR: SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED 'DATA' (T_STRING) ....
alguna ayuda ?

Comment: Creo que $f['imagen'] debe de ser $fila['imagen'], ¿no?

Comment: Qué es `$f['imagen']` ??

Comment: es $fila['imagen'], pero ese no es mi problema

Comment: Por lo que respondes en tus comentarios a la respuesta que hay, ese SÍ es tu problema. Estás pintando el nombre del archivo mas no su ruta absoluta. El servidor tiene que saber de dónde cargar la imagen, no sólo el nombre.

Comment: ya lo corregi y sigue sin salir la imagen que deseo, atraves de mi búsqueda.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un pequeño error al momento de recorrer el while, al parecer estas tratando de imprimir un php dentro de un php, espero que te funcione.

```
  while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    header("Content-type: Imagenes/jpg"); 
    $salida.="<tr>
                <td>".$fila['Num_reg']."</td>
                <td>".$fila['Dni']."</td>
                <td>".$fila['Documento']."</td>
                <td>".$fila['Contacto']."</td>
                <td>".$fila['Ubigeo']."</td>
                <td>".$fila['Fec_publicacion']."</td>
                <td><img src='".base64_encode($fila['imagen'])."'/></td>
              </tr>";
        }
      $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    }
  echo $salida;
```

Comment: Pero no me muestra la imagen, alguna otra idea?

Comment: Verifica que la $fila['imagen'], (si es una rauta, sea la correcta)

Comment: Si correcto, me aparece el icono de imagen, pero mas no la imagen que deberia de aparecer.

Comment: Si te aparece, etnonces es posible que el problema esta es en la informacion que recibes, dentro has insertado mal ruta de imagen o la imagen que no era.

Comment: Tengo inquietud, porque lo estoy utilizando para hacer una busqueda filtrada, es por eso que sentencie asi primero
   <td><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($f['imagen']);?>">
, porque esto lo use en una tabla normal y si aparece la imagen que necesito, pero en la busqueda no me jala la imagen